# BOX / JWT OAuth 2.0 by golang

Tags: go, oauth, jwt, box, jwt-go

I want to upload image from my server without user. I made box application and setting.

I try to create JWT token and got access token. after that, I try to get file information from my Box file. but this api return 404 status.

I don't know where I missed. If you know, please help me.

My code is follow as.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "time"

    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

type BoxToken struct {
    AccessToken  string   `json:"access_token"`
    ExpiresIn    int      `json:"expires_in"`
    RestrictedTo []string `json:"restricted_to"`
    TokenType    string   `json:"token_type"`
}

func main() {
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodRS512, jwt.MapClaims{
        "iss":          "application client id",
        "sub":          "enterprise id",
        "box_sub_type": "enterprise",
        "aud":          "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token",
        "jti":          "unique id",
        "exp":          time.Now().Unix() + 60,
    })
    token.Header["kid"] = "public key id"

    privateKeyData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("private.key")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    key, err := jwt.ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM(privateKeyData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Generate encoded token and send it as response.
    tokenStr, err := token.SignedString(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //fmt.Println(tokenStr)

    values := url.Values{}
    values.Add("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer")
    values.Add("client_id", "application client id")
    values.Add("client_secret", "application client secret")
    values.Add("assertion", tokenStr)

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token", strings.NewReader(values.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    client := http.DefaultClient

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)

    responseBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var boxToken BoxToken
    if err := json.Unmarshal(responseBody, &boxToken); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req2, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID?fields=id,name", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    req2.Header.Add("Authorization", `Bearer `+boxToken.AccessToken)

    resp2, err := client.Do(req2)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp2.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println(resp2.StatusCode)

    responseBody2, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp2.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(responseBody2))
}
```

and standard output is

```
404
{"type":"error","status":404,"code":"not_found","context_info":{"errors":[{"reason":"invalid_parameter","name":"item","message":"Invalid value 'f_${FILE_ID}'. 'item' with value 'f_${FILE_ID}' not found"}]},"help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Not Found","request_id":"3de39rftkndh2qqn"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to actually pass an actual file id in place of "FILE_ID" in:

`req2, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID?fields=id,name", nil)`

Based on reading the [API Reference](https://developer.box.com/reference)